It it possible to make a manual GitHub Actions job or step to deploy existing test build of Azure App to production?
I have created a simple GitHub actions workflow to deploy to the test slot for my ASP.NET core app triggered by a commit to master.
I would now like to be able go back to a given workflow in the actions history screen, and manually trigger a deploy of the same artefacts to the production slot.
Is this possible? The only way I have that semi-works right now is a 'workflow_dispatch' manual trigger but this is not linked to the code at the given commit hash that the original workflow ran. It will rebuild and deploy at the head of the default branch.

Yes,you can manually trigger the workflow by clicking Run workflow in github.

I faced that issue a month ago while implementing GitHub Actions pipeline which had to build the project on every commit but deploy only manually.
I solved this by adding a step to the workflow which checks if the image with such commit hash already exists in the registry and if yes skip all the build steps. So you run the whole workflow every time but if the build you need already exists only deploy part of the workflow will be run.
